# Invalid object name 'ASPState.dbo.ASPStateTempApplications' - Exception after renaming the ASPState Database

Tags: asp.net, session-state, sql-session-state

I have created new session database using the command (aspnet_regsql.exe -S  -E -ssadd -sstype p) and it created DB called ASPState. Then I renamed it to something like E_ASPStateDB. I have configured the correct DB name in the sessionState connection string. But  still it throws the exception **Invalid object name 'ASPState.dbo.ASPStateTempApplications'**

What i need to do, so that it will use the new database name?

Comment: Not sure but i guess DB name is hard coded by MS, one suggestion would be to run profiler and see the the query being sent.

Answer (score 16):

I ran this on the db server that the site was connecting to and it solved it immediately.

```
USE [ASPState]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CreateTempTables]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: This solved my issue immediately, but each time I restart my server, I have to run this. Is there a better way to make this change permanant on server?

Answer (score 4):

Since you renamed the DB you will have to regenerate the ASPnet session tables. Below is the solution to it.

```
To Remove, use the following command: [open visual studio command prompt]

aspnet_regsql -ssremove -S [SERVER] -U [USER] -P [PWD] -d [DATABASE] -sstype c

Then add them again by following command

aspnet_regsql -ssadd -S [SERVER] -U [USER] -P [PWD] -d [DATABASE] -sstype c
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

You must modify the stored procedures because they invoke the tables with the database name and schema, as follows:

[ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempApplications

you have to change it for

[E_ASPStateDB].dbo.ASPStateTempApplications

Comment: after modifying the references to new database name in stored procedures, session started working for me

Answer (score 0):

once you have registered a DB name using aspnet_regsql, you shall have to use the name you registered with. There is no point really to change the name afterwards. If you really want to use a name like E_ASPStateDB, why not delete the registration of ASPState first and then re-registering with the name E_ASPStateDB. It shall make your life easier

Comment: Yeas we need to remove earlier registration to use new db name as we have one to one relationship only.